# Saving Azure Form Recognizer Invoice Results in CSV

Tags: python, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, azure-form-recognizer

I am using the sample Python script to extract invoice or a batch of invoices into a CSV file

given https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-quickstart-code/blob/master/python/FormRecognizer/rest/python-invoices.md

```
########### Python Form Recognizer Async Invoice #############

import json
import time
import os
import ntpath
import sys
from requests import get, post
import csv


def analyzeInvoice(filename):
    invoiceResultsFilename = filename + ".invoice.json"

    # do not run analyze if .invoice.json file is present on disk
    if os.path.isfile(invoiceResultsFilename):
        with open(invoiceResultsFilename) as json_file:
            return json.load(json_file)

    # Endpoint URL
    endpoint = r"XXXXXXXXX"
    apim_key = "XXXXXXXXX"
    post_url = endpoint + "/formrecognizer/v2.1/prebuilt/invoice/analyzeResults"
    headers = {
        # Request headers
        'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream',
        'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': apim_key,
    }

    params = {
        "includeTextDetails": True
    }

    with open(filename, "rb") as f:
        data_bytes = f.read()

    try:
        resp = post(url = post_url, data = data_bytes, headers = headers, params = params)
        if resp.status_code != 202:
            print("POST analyze failed:\n%s" % resp.text)
            return None
        print("POST analyze succeeded: %s" % resp.headers["operation-location"])
        get_url = resp.headers["operation-location"]
    except Exception as e:
        print("POST analyze failed:\n%s" % str(e))
        return None

    n_tries = 50
    n_try = 0
    wait_sec = 6

    while n_try < n_tries:
        try:
            resp = get(url = get_url, headers = {"Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key": apim_key})
            resp_json = json.loads(resp.text)
            if resp.status_code != 200:
                print("GET Invoice results failed:\n%s" % resp_json)
                return None
            status = resp_json["status"]
            if status == "succeeded":
                print("Invoice analysis succeeded.")
                with open(invoiceResultsFilename, 'w') as outfile:
                    json.dump(resp_json, outfile, indent=4)
                return resp_json
            if status == "failed":
                print("Analysis failed:\n%s" % resp_json)
                return None
            # Analysis still running. Wait and retry.
            time.sleep(wait_sec)
            n_try += 1
        except Exception as e:
            msg = "GET analyze results failed:\n%s" % str(e)
            print(msg)
            return None

    return resp_json

def parseInvoiceResults(resp_json):
    docResults = resp_json["analyzeResult"]["documentResults"]
    invoiceResult = {}
    for docResult in docResults:
        for fieldName, fieldValue in sorted(docResult["fields"].items()):
            valueFields = list(filter(lambda item: ("value" in item[0]) and ("valueString" not in item[0]), fieldValue.items()))
            invoiceResult[fieldName] = fieldValue["text"]
            if len(valueFields) == 1:
                print("{0:26} : {1:50}      NORMALIZED VALUE: {2}".format(fieldName , fieldValue["text"], valueFields[0][1]))
                invoiceResult[fieldName + "_normalized"] = valueFields[0][1]
            else:
                print("{0:26} : {1}".format(fieldName , fieldValue["text"]))
    print("")
    return invoiceResult

def main(argv):
    if (len(argv)  != 2):
        print("ERROR: Please provide invoice filename or root directory with invoice PDFs/images as an argument to the python script")
        return

    # list of invoice to analyze
    invoiceFiles = []
    csvPostfix = '-invoiceResults.csv'
    if os.path.isfile(argv[1]):
        # Single invoice
        invoiceFiles.append(argv[1])
        csvFileName = argv[1] + csvPostfix
    else:
        # Folder of invoices
        supportedExt = ['.pdf', '.jpg','.jpeg','.tif','.tiff','.png','.bmp']
        invoiceDirectory = argv[1]
        csvFileName = os.path.join(invoiceDirectory, os.path.basename(os.path.abspath(invoiceDirectory)) + csvPostfix)
        for root, directories, filenames in os.walk(invoiceDirectory):
            for invoiceFilename in filenames:
                ext = os.path.splitext(invoiceFilename)[-1].lower()
                if ext in supportedExt:
                    fullname = os.path.join(root, invoiceFilename)
                    invoiceFiles.append(fullname)

    with open(csvFileName, mode='w', newline='\n', encoding='utf-8') as csv_file:
        fieldnames = ['Filename',
                      'FullFilename','InvoiceTotal','InvoiceTotal_normalized','AmountDue','AmountDue_normalized','SubTotal','SubTotal_normalized','TotalTax','TotalTax_normalized','CustomerName','VendorName',
                      'InvoiceId','CustomerId','PurchaseOrder','InvoiceDate','InvoiceDate_normalized','DueDate','DueDate_normalized',
                      'VendorAddress','VendorAddressRecipient','BillingAddress','BillingAddressRecipient','ShippingAddress','ShippingAddressRecipient','CustomerAddress','CustomerAddressRecipient','ServiceAddress','ServiceAddressRecipient','RemittanceAddress','RemittanceAddressRecipient', 'ServiceStartDate','ServiceStartDate_normalized','ServiceEndDate','ServiceEndDate_normalized','PreviousUnpaidBalance','PreviousUnpaidBalance_normalized']
        writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, fieldnames=fieldnames)
        writer.writeheader()
        counter = 0
        for invoiceFullFilename in invoiceFiles:
            counter = counter + 1
            invoiceFilename = ntpath.basename(invoiceFullFilename)
            print("----- Processing {0}/{1} : {2} -----".format(counter, len(invoiceFiles),invoiceFullFilename))

            resp_json = analyzeInvoice(invoiceFullFilename)

            if (resp_json is not None):
                invoiceResults = parseInvoiceResults(resp_json)
                invoiceResults["FullFilename"] = invoiceFullFilename
                invoiceResults["Filename"] = invoiceFilename
                writer.writerow(invoiceResults)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(sys.argv)
```

When I am running the code `PS C:\Users\absf\Desktop\Projects\Azure_FR\fr_azure> python fr_azure.py "C:\Users\absf\Desktop\Projects\Azure_FR\invoices"`

on terminal, its giving the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "fr_azure.py", line 139, in <module>
    main(sys.argv)
  File "fr_azure.py", line 133, in main
    invoiceResults = parseInvoiceResults(resp_json)
  File "fr_azure.py", line 84, in parseInvoiceResults
    invoiceResult[fieldName] = fieldValue["text"]
KeyError: 'text'
```

Please help in resolving the error

Answer (score 0):

It looks like documentation was not updated to support invoice line items feature in 2.1 version. "Items" field does not have text property and it causes the crash. Simplest workaround to add a condition below at line 82 to ignore "Items" field from processing:

```
        ...
        for fieldName, fieldValue in sorted(docResult["fields"].items()):
             if fieldName != "Items":
                 valueFields = list(filter(lambda item: ("value" in item[0]) and ("valueString" not in item[0]), fieldValue.items()))
        ...
```

Sample script in documentation will be updated soon with full line items support.

Comment: Documentation was updated, please use latest script here: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-quickstart-code/blob/master/python/FormRecognizer/rest/python-invoices.md